# why this Datetime works like this?

Tags: datetime

I have 2 datetimes with fixed values: 2020-09-12T**18**:13:41Z

```
  <lightning:input aura:id="stst" type="datetime" name="input3" label="{!$Label.c.Start_Date_Time}" required="true" value="2020-09-12T18:13:41Z" class="slds-size--1-of-2 slds-p-horizontal_x-small"/>
  <ui:inputDateTime aura:id="expdate" label="Expense Date" class="form-control" value="2020-09-12T18:13:41Z" displayDatePicker="true" />
```

but my UI its showing that its 20 PM  Why?

[image]

thanks!

Edited:

I cant adjust because when I save the record the correct value "18" is displayed. Also have multiple timezones, more than 4 countries

[image]

[image]

SOLUTION:
To set your Datetime you need to set it with UTC

for example if your GMT is GMT+3 and the current time its 18:00

you have to set: 15:00

your component its gonna display 18:00

but the value that its gonna be save will be 15:00 with a final Z that means UTC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're in GMT+02:00. The time you specified is in GMT+00:00 (that's what the "Z" in the time string represents). The UI automatically translates the time to your local time zone, so it ends up being 20 instead.

Comment: if I remove the Z the dateime its not displayed, how can I specify a timezone?

Comment: @TomasGarciaEtchegaray There's a separate attribute you can set, `timezone`, that allows you to specify a timezone to use for input/output.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce stores datetime as UTC/GMT. It will automatically convert the offset depending on your local time zone so if you look at your time zone setting of your org you can do the difference and adjust your hard coded value accordingly.

In this case, you want 16 instead of 18.

Comment: I cant adjust because when I save the record the correct value "18" is displayed